# How to search for a specific date(2010-12-01) which is of dtype: object in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

I have a pandas series(df1['Dates']) which represent dates(without time) and are of object datatype:

```
df1['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['InvoiceDate']).dt.date
```

(where the InvoiceDate is of dtype:datetime64[ns])

```
df1.Dates

        0         2010-12-01
        1         2010-12-01
        2         2010-12-01
        3         2010-12-01
        4         2010-12-01
                     ...    
        541904    2011-12-09
        541905    2011-12-09
        541906    2011-12-09
        541907    2011-12-09
        541908    2011-12-09

Name: Dates, Length: 541909, dtype: object
```

Now to search a specific date in df1['Dates'] ,say "2010-12-01" using "==" operator the **output I am getting is empty**, though the given date is present in dataset:

```
df1[df1.Dates=="2010-12-01"]
```

Where am I doing wrong?? or is there any another way for searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-hand side of your equality operator should be of the same type as the elements (dtype) of df1['Dates'], which is datetime.date the way you set it up. So the following should work

```
import datetime
df1[df1['Dates'] == datetime.date(day = 1,month = 12,year = 2010)]
```

or

```
df1[df1['Dates'] == datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-12-01','%Y-%m-%d').date()]
```

Comment: You may have meant:
df1[df1['Dates'] == datetime.strptime('2010-12-01','%Y-%m-%d').date()]  .
and not 
df1[df1['Dates'] == datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-12-01','%Y-%m-%d').date()]

Comment: well it depends if you do `import datetime` or `from datetime import datetime` :-)